# Problems installation of camera drivers - linux

Tags: linux, camera, usb, driver

I want to install the drivers of the video camera on my linux computer.
I write the command:
modprobe usbserial vendor=... product=...

what I expected to get was ttyUSB0 (or sth simmilar) in the /dev directory.

Instead what is getting installed is sg3 (whatever that is) and when I run a program that is supposed to send a command to start recording I get no results (but no errors either).
(I changed what I had previously: fd = open(/dev/ttyUSB0,...) to /dev/sg3 but I guess this is not a configuration that enables sending this kind of data.

What might be the problem? (Sorry if it's a basic question)

Answer (score 0):

cameras and linux can be tricky.
Start by plugging in the camera and running

```
lsusb
```

google for the id to see if anyone has a step by step tutorial or at very least can tell you which modules are needed.

Most common drivers seem to have been migrated to the kernel, so rebulid your kernel make sure the modules are built.
Some more obscure usb modules have to be built by hand.

Comment: I did lsusb before, I got the product and vendor id. Then I ran the command modprobe usbserial vendor=... product=... And I know that before and on another computer it used to work. I'll try to find sth more on google..